# Allure report: index.html shows nothing in both firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jestjs, allure

When I run the command allure serve I get a valid allure dashboard on the browser, but when I run allure generate the index.html from the allure report looks pretty empty and showing nothing in both chrome after running --allow-file-access-from-files  and in  Firefox.
this is how the html file looks:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Allure Report</title>
    <link rel="favicon" href="favicon.ico?v=2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/screen-diff/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="alert"></div>
<div id="content">
    <span class="spinner">
        <span class="spinner__circle"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="popup"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/behaviors/index.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/packages/index.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/screen-diff/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the text or HTML content..? Is it written with the JavaScript or you accidentally missed it?

Comment: thats extactly what i dont understand, when i run allure generate i see a new directory allure-report at the root of my project, then when accessing the  file index.html in the directory this is what i get

Comment: Can you please add pictures of both the cases...

Comment: i think i had a problem with the installation of allure-command line and jest-allure, i simply re-installed them and it works fine! thanks for the help!